# Workaround for cross-site parameters reaching max URL limit

Tags: php, javascript, html, apache, cross-domain

We are developing a bookmarklet, and we use JSONP to communicate with the server. We have reached a phase when we must send from the browser to server parameters that will exceed the well know 2000ish URL length.

We are looking for solutions to overcome this problem. Please note that the bookmarklet will be executed on 3rd party URLS, some of them are HTTP and some of them HTTPS, and JSONP is limited to GET requests only

Comment: can you zip them? using a/the zip/compression algorithm?

Comment: @Erik: The JSONP technique is not just a format, and it *is* limited the GET. How can you POST from a `<script>` element?

Comment: AJAX in general is **NOT** limited to GET, you can use POST too. And yes, POST **IS** the only way to overcome GET length limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of would be to do multiple requests - throw an id in with the request and setup the state server side in a persistent way and then request the data.

Multiple requests is pretty ugly too - what if one message gets lost while another makes it, etc.

Unfortunately, JSONP doesn't have a lot of flexibility since its just simulating script loads - and theres really no way around this with current browser security standards.

Answer (score 0):

With the know limitations, I see only three ways:

- Send less data. Potentially you could compress it?
- Use more than one request. This can be complicated for blobs, but should be possible.
- Extend the URL length limit - there are configs for that in your server

Comment: the last one is also a browser config, or the server config affects how browsers limit the URL?

Comment: Yeah, there may be some browser limits (and I expect them to be comparably low in IE), but afaik the server (apache?) limit is lower than it needs to be.